# Adjust brightness and contrast of BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing

I'm processing a bunch of images with some framework, and all I'm given is a bunch of `BufferedImage` objects. Unfortunately, these images are really dim, and I'd like to brighten them up and adjust the contrast a little.

Something like:

```
BufferedImage image = something.getImage();
image = new Brighten(image).brighten(0.3); // for 30%
image = new Contrast(image).contrast(0.3);
// ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That was easy, actually.

```
RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(1.2f, 15, null);
rescaleOp.filter(image, image);  // Source and destination are the same.
```

A `scaleFactor` of 1.2 and `offset` of 15 seems to make the image about a stop brighter.

Yay!

Read more in [the docs for `RescaleOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html).

Comment: What is a range of scaleFactor and offset?

Comment: @ADTC http://www.photographymad.com/pages/view/what-is-a-stop-of-exposure-in-photography

Comment: Scale of 1.2 is +20%. Every value is multiplied by 1.2, so what used to be 100% becomes 120% (quoting javadoc on RescaleOp, "dstElement = (srcElement*scaleFactor) + offset")

Comment: Offset 15 is not that clear though, this may need an adjustment depending on a color channel sample size for a particular BufferedImage.

Comment: is Offset value 15 is used to change the contrast of the image