# How to increase/decrease brightness of an image with the use of JSlider slider or JScrollBar

Tags: java, image-processing, jscrollbar

i Had load my image Buffered image now need to brighten it using Slider or scroll-bar
so could any one suggest me how to do it? If it can done using any ImageJ library then suggest me that also.

Comment: here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html this might get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similiar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433275/adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-bufferedimage-in-java). You will need to adjust values based on readings from your slider

Comment: Please paste that link of that answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433275/adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-bufferedimage-in-java