# RGB retrieval of a coloured image

Tags: java, image, bitmap, rgb, brightness

I am trying to do some image processing on a coloured image and for me to do so I need to separate the RGB values and modify them separately. I am just implementing a increase in brightness filter. I am doing this in java. Can someone help me out please

Comment: You must post your code to get help. This isn't "ask for solution" site, it's for getting advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

First, you need to be able to load an image that supports the `BufferedImage` class.  For this, you're best using the `ImageIO` API.  Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).

Once you have this, you can obtain the pixel information in a verity of ways.

One of the simplest is to use [`BufferedImage#getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29), which returns a packed integer of the pixel.

Depending on the type of image, you can obtain the individual color values [`Color(int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29), which will unpack the integer accordingly (you can also do this manually, but I never remember the maths and this is simpler).

Alternativly, you can access the [`Raster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html) directly, via [`BufferedImage#getData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData%28%29), which provides you access to more methods for manipulating the underlying pixel information (such as grabbing regions of pixels for example)

Now, if all that sounds like more fun then you can handle, you can easily perform image brightening using a `BufferedImageOp`...

See, [Adjust brightness and contrast of BufferedImage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433275/adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-bufferedimage-in-java) and [How to change the contrast and brightness of an image stored as pixel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105521/how-to-change-the-contrast-and-brightness-of-an-image-stored-as-pixel-values) and [Change brightness of image using RescaleOp](http://javaingrab.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/change-brightness-of-image-using.html) for examples (these where just the top few that popped up on Google)