# How do I test a pixel of a bufferedimage for a certain color in Java

Tags: java, image, pixel, bufferedimage

I'm trying to take a screenshot and then look through it for a pixel that has a certain color. Firstly, I tried to just print the color of an image at a certain xy coordinate but I could not even do that. What am I doing wrong?

```
static int ScreenWidth;
static int ScreenHeight;
static Robot robot;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic 
    callibrateScreenSize();
    findSquares();
    //takeScreenShot();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void callibrateScreenSize() {

    try {
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        ScreenWidth = captureSize.width;
        ScreenHeight = captureSize.height;
        System.out.println("Width is " + ScreenWidth);
        System.out.println("Height is " + ScreenHeight);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return null;
}

public static BufferedImage takeScreenShot() {
    Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
    return image;
}

public static void findSquares() {
    System.out.println(takeScreenShot().getRGB(5,5));
}
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: What do you get for output?

Comment: For an output I got the dimensions of the picture and then an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BufferedImage#getRGB` or `byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()` to get the pixel data.  `getRBG` is more convenient, but is typically slower than getting the pixel array

`getRGB` packs the pixel data into an `int`, `getData` will return the RGB(A) in each entry of the array (`R = n; G = n+1; B=n+2(, A=n+3)`), so will need to process this yourself

You can use `java.awt.Color`, which allows you to access the RGB values of the color, pack it as a `int` value or convert an `int` to a `Color`

```
Color color = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0), true);
int redColor = Color.RED.getRGB();
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) provides an example of dealing with the `byte[]` pixel data

Basically, you will need to loop over the data, comparing the values in the image to the value you are after, either directly (comparing the red, green and blue values) or indirectly, comparing the packed `int` or `Color` values.

Personally, I'd grab the pixel data, convert each element to an `int` and compare it with a previously packed `int` from a `Color` object, this creates the less number of short lived objects and should be reasonably efficient

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444587/getting-pixel-rgb-from-a-bufferedimage-from-the-mouses-x-and-y-possition/21445320#21445320) which use `getRGB` to get the red, green, blue values from a given pixel

Comment: Ohh okay so if I want to test every pixel in a picture I can set up a loop and cycle through all the pixels by using `Color` and testing color? My only question now is why does printing out a `getRGB()` not work? Also how do I test for a very specific color?

Comment: `getRGB` returns an `int` (packed pixel), as I said, I would start by creating a `Color` of the color you want to find and use `Color#getRGB` to return the packed `int` value for that color.  It would then compare the result with the values from `BufferedImage#getRGB`

Comment: Why am I unable to run this in a method?
`Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(0, 0), true);`

Comment: Where do you create an instance of `Robot`?

Comment: At the beginning of the class. Right now I'm trying to use getRBG() and checking the color using bit shifting and masking as per a friends advice

Comment: Don't see where you initialise an instance of `Robot`, I see where you declare a variable of type `Robot`, but you never initialise it.  I run your code (after I initialised `robot`) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I wrote a while ago using the Robot class. It returns an array of the screen wherever the screen is white, it was not very computationally expensive for my application, but I found probing the values individually using robot was. At first I didn't even read your question, but looking back, I think this will help you A LOT. Good luck. And then I saw the original post date...

```
public boolean[][] raster() throws AWTException, IOException{
   boolean[][] filled= new boolean[720][480];
  BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,720,480));
//accepts (xCoord,yCoord, width, height) of screen
    for (int n =0; n<720; n++){
          for (int m=0; m<480; m++){
              if(new Color(image.getRGB(n, m)).getRed()<254){   
//can check any rgb value, I just chose red in this case to check for white pixels    
                  filled[n][m]=true;
              }
          }
        }
      return filled;
}
```