# Find specific color Java

Tags: java, colors

I am still learning Java, so please be patient if the question is too easy.. I am trying to find a specific color in a if-condition, let's say blue (RGB: (0,0,225)) by analyzing a picture pixel by pixel with the following for-loop:

```
    public void findColor(){     

            for (int w=0; w< this.width; w++){
                for(int h=0; h< this.height; h++){

                    if(this.Picture[w][h]=??){
```

I also have another class to specify the RGB color:

```
 public class Color {

    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;

    public Color(int r, int g, int b){
        this.red=r;
        this.green=g;
        this.blue=b;
    }

    public Color(Color c){
        this.red=c.red;
        this.green=c.green;
        this.blue=c.blue;
    }

    public void setColor(int r, int g, int b){
        this.red= r;
        this.green= g;
        this.blue = b;
    }

    public int colorRed(){
        return this.red;
    }

    public int colorGreen(){
        return this.green;
    }


    public int colorBlue(){
        return this.blue;
    }
}
```

My question is, how to connect those two classes in order to check for the RGB color of a pixel?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Detect a particular colon ? Detect witch color each pixel is ? BTW, classname in Java usually starts with a capital letter ;)

Comment: As I said I am trying to evaluate in my if condition if given pixel is blue, if it is then I'll change it to another color, but I know how to handle the second part :)

Comment: You could give your Color class an equals method, one which would compare the rgb values of another Color class, and then the test could be `if (x.equals(y))`. But why are you re-inventing the wheel? Why create your own Color class when others already exist?

Answer (score 1):

At first I would change the method head `findColor ()` to `findColor (Color aColor)`. So you can re-use this method.

You didn't give us any hints what the mystic `Picture` is. But if you save the image in a `BufferedImage`, you can get the RGB-Color by calling `Picture.getRGB(x,y)`. More documentation in [BufferedImage on oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29).

In your example it would be int `int packedInt = img.getRGB(w, h);` Then you should convert this value to a Color Object. `Color myColor = new Color(packedInt, true);`

At this point you should think about to use the standard JAVA Color class instead of your class.

Now you can compare the actual `myColor` with the input field of your Method.

EDIT: there is a similar issue to yours at stackowerflow:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444587/getting-pixel-rgb-from-a-bufferedimage-from-the-mouses-x-and-y-possition)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this for getting color of pixels

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("your_file.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
              int pixel = image.getRGB(w, h);
              int red = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
              int green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
              int blue = pixel & 0x000000ff;
              System.out.println("Red Color value = " + red);
              System.out.println("Green Color value = " + green);
              System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + blue);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

it should work, you need to add your test and else for changing color of pixel, if you have some problem with this just ask