# Java OCR program using tesseract in Windows

Tags: java, netbeans, ocr, tesseract

I just started trying to write a simple java code to do some simple OCR, using the code and advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835831/recognizing-numbers-in-an-image-in-java).

I have installed libraries, and the project in the IDE (NetBeans) looks like the picture I have attached.

I'm getting these errors:

10:47:30.099 [main] WARN net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs - Source 'C:\Users\Simon%20Bothner\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OCRTest\build\classes\win32-x86-64' does not exist

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 
'C:\Users\Simon%20Bothner\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OCRTest\build\classes\win32-x86-64' does not exist

```
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.copyResources(LoadLibs.java:138)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.extractTessResources(LoadLibs.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.<clinit>(LoadLibs.java:59)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:263)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:403)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:502)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:481)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:77)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

C:\Users\Simon Bothner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I tried to use [this](http://tphangout.com/how-to-use-the-tesseract-api-to-perform-ocr-in-your-java-code/) tutorial, but I seemed to be missing a .dll, the liblept168.dll...

Can someone help me with this? I'm quite new at this and can't seem to get this to work...

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Maybe this answer could help to locate the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547211/issue-with-the-libtesseract303-dll-in-netbeans#35553331

Comment: Tess4J Tutorial page includes NetBeans example: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/

Comment: Checked out the answer, will try to get it to work, thanks! :)

Tried following the tutorial, but couldn't get it to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: http://tphangout.com/how-to-use-the-tesseract-api-to-perform-ocr-in-your-java-code/
Open the link above and see how to install Tesseract in Java properly.

Step 2: After reading it, if you still get the error like "library not open", download Microsoft Visual Studio >12.0, and also update your JDK version (I also get the same error).

Step 3:

```
public class tesserct 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "64".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "lib/win32-x86" : "lib/win32-x86-64");

        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "32".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "lib/win32-x86" : "lib/win32-x86-64");

        File imageFile = new File("F:\\Wallpaper & photo\\wallpaper\\holi wollpepar\\happy-holi-2013-hd-wallpaper1.jpg");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
        // ITesseract instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping
        File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata"); // Maven build bundles English data
        instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getParent());

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

run the code above on your NetBeans, and try it.