# Adjust brightness and contrast using RescaleOp

Tags: java, image, image-processing, colors, bufferedimage

Im trying to adjust the brightness and contrast of an image in Java, ive seen that using RescaleOp is one of the easiest ways of doing this, however, no matter what I change the values to it seems to adjust the brightness and contrast at the same time but I want to adjust them independently.
The code I have at the moment is:

```
RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(0.6f, 1, null); //decrease contrast
rescaleOp.filter(redImage, redImage);
```

But as I say, its decreasing both, anyone know how to make it so it just adjusts contrast and just adjusts brightness?

Comment: There is a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433275/adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-bufferedimage-in-java

Comment: Also, my guess is you do not require an offset of 1. Your scale faction of 0.6f should do the trick of contrast. I have not tried it, but this is a suggestion after reading the doc.