# How do I change contrast of a png file using java

Tags: java, image, file

I made a program to take a picture of myself and text it to me whenever I enter in the wrong code, but the picture is very hard to see without turning the screen on my phone. I think the contrast is too low, but I have no clue on how to do this. My code saves the picture to a png file and sends that to me, so it has to be a file (and not to a JFrame like how I saw in everything I found online)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433275/adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-bufferedimage-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You could use [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) to increase the contrast/visibility. See the section of Examples - Full sized image for a grayscale example.

There are already implementations available, so you don't have do it yourself. One of which I found here, which appears to preserve the color: [HistogramEqualizer.java by a Student of Tunghai University](http://web.thu.edu.tw/s912836/www/code/equlization/HistogramEqualizer.java).